# How to download data from macrotrends web site with R?

Tags: r, web-scraping, download, rvest

I found some time ago this R code edited by Greg (here) and it worked very well for a long time. Unfortunately, some time ago, it stopped working, (at least for me) and I am wondering if someone could help to fix the problem if it is possible.

```
library(rvest)
webpage <- read_html("https://www.macrotrends.net/stocks/charts/azo/autozone/pe-ratio")
html <- rvest::html_nodes(webpage, "thead+ thead th , #style-1 td")
results <- rvest::html_text(html)

Date <- results[seq(5, length(results), 4)]
`Stock Price` <- results[seq(6, length(results), 4)]
`TTM Net EPS` <- results[seq(7, length(results), 4)]
`PE Ratio` <- results[seq(8, length(results), 4)]
results <- data.frame(Date, `Stock Price`, `TTM Net EPS`, `PE Ratio`, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Returning

```
head(results)
        Date Stock.Price TTM.Net.EPS PE.Ratio
1 2020-04-27     1060.52                16.25
2 2020-02-29     1032.51      $65.27    15.82
3 2019-11-30     1177.92      $64.37    18.30
4 2019-08-31     1101.69      $63.54    17.34
5 2019-05-31     1027.11      $55.97    18.35
6 2019-02-28      938.97      $53.40    17.58
```

But as I said, sadly seem not working anymore. If somebody could help, It will be very nice for R world.

Comment: The code still works, it's just lacking the session function before `read_html()`. In `rvest`, you have to open a session before scraping the html from a webpage.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response, Bastian. I am not so expert in rvest. But if it helps in some way to everybody newbie like me, I replaced read_html() with session() and seem to work well now.

Comment: The `here` bit doesn't actually link to anything

Comment: Also, this code works as-is on my computer- do you get an error Enrique? What happens?

Comment: @Mark, there's probably a load balancer or something that routes requests depending on our location/network, so we are likely seeing different behaviour. For me the issue is reproducible and  `read_html()` returns error 403. Making that same request with httr(2)  and setting  `Accept: text/html`  in header makes it work.

Comment: hmmm interesting @margusl, thank you for sharing! I wonder if setting that header fixes things generally, or that just flipped the response the server gave you from a negative one to a positive one

Comment: Mark: yes, read_html() returns error 403 to me. But as I said, and thanks to Bastian, I fix it replacing read_html() with session().

Comment: @Margust: Thank you for your comment. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: Now `httr2::request()` works as well, without setting/changing any header value (still 403 with `read_html()`). Go figure...  @EnriqueL, if just replacing `read_html()` with `session()` works for you and you are after a minimal change, I'd stick with that.

Comment: @BastiánOleaHerrera it would be interesting/informative if you could write an answer for this. I'm particularly interested in why you said "In rvest, you have to open a session before scraping the html from a webpage", when this code seems to work well without that for me and others

Comment: What is the error message You get? Have You done anything to investigate the problem before asking this question? Have You checked this code on another machine so You can be sure the problem is in code, not in your machine configuration?

Comment: @JakubMałecki. The error message was 403. I investigate yes, even if I don't understand many of the documentation that I found. I tried a lot before to come here. I try in another computer with RStudio but continue to return the same error. When you don't have privileges, it is so difficult to communicate without any other option that made a question. There is another way to communicate here different that a question?. All the easy ways to have the information point to Python, but I would like to continue to use R and find the solution in R.

Comment: Despite the negative votes there is a nice community here that really wants to help everybody. Thank you to all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least in R & RStudio running on Windows, `User-Agent` in `rvest::read_html()` request header is something like:

```
RStudio Desktop (2023.6.2.529); R (4.2.3 x86_64-w64-mingw32 x86_64 mingw32)
```

Apararently they really dislike the `RStudio Desktop` part, a demo with `httr2` for convenience.
Set User-Agent to something that includes `RStudio Desktop` and the request will fail:

```r
library(httr2)
url_ <- "https://www.macrotrends.net/stocks/charts/azo/autozone/pe-ratio"

request(url_) |>
  req_user_agent("RStudio Desktop") |>
  req_perform(verbosity = 1)
#> -> GET /stocks/charts/azo/autozone/pe-ratio HTTP/1.1
#> -> Host: www.macrotrends.net
#> -> User-Agent: RStudio Desktop
#> -> Accept: */*
#> -> Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
#> -> 
#> <- HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
#> <- Connection: close
#> <- Content-Length: 420
#> <- Server: Varnish
#> <- Retry-After: 0
#> <- Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
#> <- Accept-Ranges: bytes
#> <- Date: Fri, 22 Sep 2023 13:16:06 GMT
#> <- Via: 1.1 varnish
#> <- X-Served-By: cache-hel1410024-HEL
#> <- X-Cache: MISS
#> <- X-Cache-Hits: 0
#> <- X-Timer: S1695388567.783692,VS0,VE0
#> <-
#> Error in `req_perform()`:
#> ! HTTP 403 Forbidden.
#> Backtrace:
#>     ▆
#>  1. └─httr2::req_perform(req_user_agent(request(url_), "RStudio Desktop"), verbosity = 1)
#>  2.   └─httr2:::resp_abort(resp, error_body(req, resp), call = error_call)
#>  3.     └─rlang::abort(...)
```

Change one character in User-Agent and we are worthy of a status 200 and content:

```r
request(url_) |>
  req_user_agent("RStudio.Desktop") |>
  req_perform(verbosity = 1)
#> -> GET /stocks/charts/azo/autozone/pe-ratio HTTP/1.1
#> -> Host: www.macrotrends.net
#> -> User-Agent: RStudio.Desktop
#> -> Accept: */*
#> -> Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
#> -> 
#> <- HTTP/1.1 200 OK
#> <- Connection: keep-alive
#> <- Content-Length: 14962
#> <- Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
#> <- Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
#> <- Pragma: no-cache
#> <- Expires: 0
#> <- Content-Encoding: gzip
#> <- Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
#> <- Via: 1.1 varnish, 1.1 varnish
#> <- Accept-Ranges: bytes
#> <- Date: Fri, 22 Sep 2023 13:16:07 GMT
#> <- Age: 1763
#> <- X-Served-By: cache-iad-kjyo7100051-IAD, cache-hel1410025-HEL
#> <- X-Cache: MISS, HIT
#> <- X-Cache-Hits: 0, 2
#> <- X-Timer: S1695388567.044209,VS0,VE0
#> <- Vary: Accept-Encoding
#> <-
#> <httr2_response>
#> GET https://www.macrotrends.net/stocks/charts/azo/autozone/pe-ratio
#> Status: 200 OK
#> Content-Type: text/html
#> Body: In memory (60149 bytes)
```

When switching to `rvest::session()`, things magically work as the default User-Agent for `session()` requests is different:

```
libcurl/7.84.0 r-curl/5.0.2 httr/1.4.7
```

So either use `session()` instead of `read_html()` as suggested in comments or use some other means to request a page content with a different user-agent, you can still parse the response with `rvest`. Here's an example with `httr2`:

```r
library(rvest)
library(httr2)
# make a request with httr2 ..
request("https://www.macrotrends.net/stocks/charts/azo/autozone/pe-ratio") |>
  req_user_agent("libcurl") |>
  req_perform() |>
  resp_body_html() |>
  #... and parse with rvest:
  html_elements("thead+ thead th , #style-1 td")
#> {xml_nodeset (232)}
#>  [1] <th style="text-align:center;">Date</th>
#>  [2] <th style="text-align:center;">Stock Price</th>
#>  [3] <th style="text-align:center;">TTM Net EPS</th>
#>  [4] <th style="text-align:center;">PE Ratio</th>
#>  [5] <td style="text-align:center;">2023-09-21</td>
#>  [6] <td style="text-align:center;">2530.76</td>
#>  [7] <td style="text-align:center;"></td>
#>  [8] <td style="text-align:center;">29.36</td>
#>  [9] <td style="text-align:center;">2023-08-31</td>
#> [10] <td style="text-align:center;">2531.33</td>
#> [11] <td style="text-align:center;">$86.21</td>
#> [12] <td style="text-align:center;">29.36</td>
#> [13] <td style="text-align:center;">2023-05-31</td>
#> [14] <td style="text-align:center;">2386.84</td>
#> [15] <td style="text-align:center;">$126.72</td>
#> [16] <td style="text-align:center;">18.84</td>
#> [17] <td style="text-align:center;">2023-02-28</td>
#> [18] <td style="text-align:center;">2486.54</td>
#> [19] <td style="text-align:center;">$121.63</td>
#> [20] <td style="text-align:center;">20.44</td>
#> ...
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

What makes it a bit more tricky to debug is the fact that the execution method plays a role here, i.e. OP's code fails when it's run in RStudio interactive session, but when executining through `reprex`,  it works as that offending string is not included in User-Agent.

Just for the reference, this is how `rvest::read_html()` fails with 403 in RStudio:

```r
library(rvest)
read_html("https://www.macrotrends.net/stocks/charts/azo/autozone/pe-ratio")
#> Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 403.
```

```
sessioninfo::platform_info()
#>  setting  value
#>  version  R version 4.2.3 (2023-03-15 ucrt)
#>  os       Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)
#>  system   x86_64, mingw32
#>  ui       RTerm
#>  language (EN)
#>  collate  Estonian_Estonia.utf8
#>  ctype    Estonian_Estonia.utf8
#>  tz       Europe/Helsinki
#>  date     2023-09-22
#>  pandoc   3.1.1 @ C:/Program Files/RStudio/resources/app/bin/quarto/bin/tools/ (via rmarkdown)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! if you don't mind me asking, how would one use session()?

Comment: @Mark, in this case it would be just a drop-in replacement for `read_html()`

Comment: @Margusl, Thank you so much for your answer. Much appreciated.