# Is it possible for a website to block scraping or is my code poorly set up?

Tags: r, web-scraping

I've heard that it's impossible for websites to block web scraping, I'm trying to scrape stock fund prices for a company, they have their funds publicly posted on a website (no login) so I'm wondering why I'm not being able to scrape them.

Here is the code for scraping the name of each stock, the date of it's latest price update and it's price:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

link <- "https://www.azvalor.com/valores-liquidativos"
page <- read_html(link)

name <- page %>% html_nodes(".sorting_1") %>% html_text()
price <- page %>% html_nodes("td:nth-child(3)") %>% html_text()
date <- page %>% html_nodes(".sorting_1+ td") %>% html_text()

stock <- data.frame(name, price, date, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

And this is the Console output when running:

```
> library(rvest)
> library(dplyr)

Attaching package: ‘dplyr’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:

    filter, lag

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

> 
> link <- "https://www.azvalor.com/valores-liquidativos"
> page <- read_html(link)
Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : Header without colon
>
```

Comment: I don't get this error, although I do get `name` and `date` as zero-length vectors (i.e. your `html_nodes()` call didn't find anything)

Comment: Actually, it is possible to website to block webscraping regarding to many factors like user-agent, behaviour. Moreover, send an http request to download the html is very detectable.

Comment: Here's one example where having  `RStudio Desktop`  in user-agent triggered the block -  https://stackoverflow.com/a/77158240/646761 . Though in this case it seems to be something related to the platform, I get the same error in Windows with 2 different curl versions (7.87 & 8.0), same with R rvest and curl  in Win (curl 8.3) . But it works fine with curl in linux (wsl, curl 7.8).  rvest/curl and  Google Colab R kernel handles it as well.