# read_html in R, Very Long Runtime

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm having incredibly long runtimes (it doesn't even finish) when trying read_html in R.  I'm thinking it's the way the page is written, perhaps intentionally, but I'm hoping I'm missing something simple or I can add an argument to fix it.  Code and URL below.

```
library(rvest)

url <- "http://www.nrc.gov/reading-rm/doc-collections/event-status/reactor-status/2022/20221203ps.html"
df <- url %>%
  read_html()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It blocks requests if the user agent includes  `RStudio Desktop`. Hopefully it's not you who triggered this ...

Failing request with `RStudio Desktop` as an user agent:

```r
library(httr2)
library(rvest)

url_ <- "https://www.nrc.gov/reading-rm/doc-collections/event-status/reactor-status/2022/20221203ps.html"
request(url_) |>
  req_user_agent("RStudio Desktop") |>
  req_timeout(1) |>
  req_perform(verbosity = 2)
#> -> GET /reading-rm/doc-collections/event-status/reactor-status/2022/20221203ps.html HTTP/1.1
#> -> Host: www.nrc.gov
#> -> User-Agent: RStudio Desktop
#> -> Accept: */*
#> -> Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
#> ->
#> Error:
#> ! Timeout was reached: [www.nrc.gov] Operation timed out after 1013 milliseconds with 0 bytes received
#> Backtrace:
#>     ▆
#>  1. └─httr2::req_perform(...)
#>  2.   └─base::tryCatch(...)
#>  3.     └─base (local) tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
#>  4.       └─base (local) tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
#>  5.         └─value[[3L]](cond)
```

And after replacing space:

```r
request(url_) |>
  req_user_agent("RStudio.Desktop") |>
  req_timeout(1) |>
  req_perform() |>
  resp_body_html() |>
  html_elements("table")
#> {xml_nodeset (4)}
#> [1] <table summary="Region 1 Power Reactor Status Report for December 03, 202 ...
#> [2] <table summary="Region 2 Power Reactor Status Report for December 03, 202 ...
#> [3] <table summary="Region 3 Power Reactor Status Report for December 03, 202 ...
#> [4] <table summary="Region 4 Power Reactor Status Report for December 03, 202 ...
```

As you'll also get a different UA string with `rvest::session()`, you can just replace `read_html()` with this:

```r
rvest::session(url_) |> 
  html_elements("table")
#> {xml_nodeset (4)}
#> [1] <table summary="Region 1 Power Reactor Status Report for December 03, 202 ...
#> [2] <table summary="Region 2 Power Reactor Status Report for December 03, 202 ...
#> [3] <table summary="Region 3 Power Reactor Status Report for December 03, 202 ...
#> [4] <table summary="Region 4 Power Reactor Status Report for December 03, 202 ...
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Oddly enough, it's not the first time I see this ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/77158240/646761 ), so perhaps "RStudio Desktop" has made it into some distributed blacklist.

Comment: I had some issues installing the httr2 package, but was finally able to get it to work and your html_elements suggestion worked for me.  Thank you!